# Install OpenCV on Windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows, opencv

On my computer I have a Dual Boot configured with Windows 10 and Ubuntu. And I need to work with a project in NodeJS that makes use of OpenCV.

To install OpenCV on Ubuntu it's simple, just run the shell file with the installation commands (print out the contents of this file below).
But I am not able to do the installation process on Windows 10 and I need it a lot, because there are programs that are not supported by Ubuntu, so I have to use Windows.

Do you know any process for installing OpenCV on Windows that really works?

P.S .: On windows, when I tried to install OpenCV, when running the project in NodeJS, I got the following error message (print also attached).

**build.sh**
[image: build.sh]

**error-print**
[image: error-print]

Comment: Note that this is an English only site. | Please, post text as text, not as screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried WSL `Windows Subsystem for Linux` ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq

basically it'll let you to have your Linux setup (Node.js + OpenCV) inside of that WSL, but it'll work on your Windows machine. On top of that, when you bind ports inside of that WSL, they will be accessible from Windows and to the windows apps.

WSL greately improves development experience and let's you avoid dual-boot.

Nit: Please always post questions only in English. StacOverflow is international community, most of the people don't speak specifically Portuguese.

Comment: Oh, sorry about the Portuguese then.
Thanks, I'll try the WSL.